# Firebase retrieval on Android does not work sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase DB Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfRcN.png)

Now i am trying to retrieve data as:

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get values for user.fullname and user.coursename
                    if (!(dataSnapshot == null)) {
                        Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        fullName = user.FullName;

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

But this does not work, on debugging Ondatachange is never executed, the variable fullName always remains null. The same happens with mostly all the other firebase retrievals, although query on a recycleradapter works like a charm.

The following is my users class:

```
     public class Users {
public String FullName;
public String CourseName;
public Users(){
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
}



@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    result.put("FullName",FullName);
    result.put("CourseName",CourseName);
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: add logging to `onCancelled` method, print databaseError to log. Maybe security rules isn't correct

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Check your db read/write rules from Firebase console. Maybe user does not have permission to retrieve that info from db.

Comment: Remember that according to documentation this callback will be called only once. So it is not called when you change something, only after first register.

Comment: @Dima, even OnCancelled is never called,error log remains empty.

Comment: @Ugurcan,following are my security rules:                                                                                                                     {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: @SebastianŚwierczek yes and i only need it once.

Comment: These rules indicate that you need to be authenticated user before retrieving any data from db. Make sure you auth first, then retry.

Comment: @UgurcanYildirim, yes I checked ,I am authenticated.